# Blender 2.9 Fluid Domain not disappearing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I am using blender 2.9, and when I try to make a fluid domain, it does not disappear.  I have tried everything, from changing resolutions, to extruding the outflow object, everything. I've checked the Liquid and Mesh options, but nothing works. Attached is my .blend file

Thank You!

[image]

Comment: There is nothing set as Inflow object for simulation ... nothing is set to be a source of liquid :)

Comment: @vklidu thanks, that worked!

Comment: I had inflow instead of outflow..